# Why are almost half the questions on the front page marked "closed"?

Tags: discussion

I peek into Programmers Stack Exchange every once in a while and I keep noticing a pattern: there are a whole lot of [CLOSED]-marked questions.  What is behind this?

- Are people unclear on what is or is not on-topic for this Stack Exchange sub-board?
- Are the permissible questions simply too narrow in scope?

In either case, what can be done to make the front page look a little less uninviting?  The way it looks now, a first-time or infrequent visitor will just see Programmers Stack Exchange as an unwelcoming place to ask questions.

Comment: see also: [So many bad questions](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7130/31260)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Are people unclear on what is or is not on-topic for this Stack Exchange sub-board?

   Oh yeah. The scope effectively made a 90° turn a few weeks into the beta, and it was a friggin' *freight train* already in terms of popularity and support even then.
2. Are the permissible questions simply too narrow in scope?

   Not really. But we're kinda trying to turn a biker bar into a tea room without kicking out the bikers first; doesn't really matter what we *say* the scope is.

Comment: I think this answer gave me the clearest understanding of the "why" of the large proportion of closed-tagged questions.

Comment: be good perhaps if you included what the scope was before and after.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think it's "half". I've told you a *million* times to stop exaggerating.

And there is some value in seeing closed questions, because..

1. People understand *there are rules and norms*, this is not some kind of "I can do whatever I want" place. So if what you want is anything goes, you might keep on moseying along to the next town.
2. People get a sense of why questions are closed, because every closed question links to the reason behind the closing, e.g.

   > #### closed as not constructive by Macneil, Mark Trapp, bigown♦ 3 hours ago
   >
   > This question does not meet enough of our [six guidelines for constructive subjective questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).

Comment: If there are a only a few closed, leaving them visible is fine.  The problem is that there are a LOT of them closed.  When I asked the question it was 40% of the visible questions on the front page.  (The ratio has gone down since then.)  Even the stats cited [here](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/492/how-to-prevent-why-is-my-question-being-closed-and-user-frustration) show that PSE is ... unusually high in the number of closed questions.

Comment: @JUST - I agree it doesn't look great but hopefully it's relatively short term.  As Jeff says, a lot of it is about showing people that there are rules and it's not just a case of anything goes (not that I think many people are thinking much before posting).